# What are the file types we can upload in Azure DevOps wiki page?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azureportal, azure-devops-wiki

[image]

I tried to upload YAML file but it is showing YAML file not supported.

I didn't find the attachment types supported in the Microsoft Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-file-structure?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a list of supported attachment file types [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#supported-in-pull-requests--wikis-2)